# Windows 10 will not update until Samsung Easy Settings is manually uninstalled

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-desktop

When I try to run the [Samsung] **Easy Settings** uninstall, Windows 10 blocks it from running saying that it is for a different version of Windows and might be unsafe.

I can't seem to find any valid or manual solutions on Samsung or Microsoft sites.

Comment: If you think this question is off topic as per Stack Overflow guidelines - consider this: I am a coder testing and using Python on Windows 10, and to test my code, I need Windows 10 to be "the latest and greatest". I have spent hours of frustration figuring this out, when instead I should have been coding- and so I now want to save other coders the same headache. Plus, I only/mainly really use Stack Overflow for all my coding related needs - so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After not finding anything useful to uninstall Samsung Easy Settings on my Windows 10 computer I had to figure this out on my own (trust me - I'm a coder ;-)**

**You will be able to uninstall Easy Settings manually and with little effort.**

**Looks like a lot - but it's pretty easy actually so stay with me.**

*Firstly I want to emphasize that you should first attempt to uninstall Samsung Easy Settings and any other programs the Windows 10 update is telling you to uninstall the proper way by opening windows settings "Add or Remove Programs" (or Apps & Features) section and then uninstalling it. If you are not able to uninstall it the normal way - then follow my instructions.*

1. Hit Ctrl+Shift+Esc (all three at once) to open your task manager (or open it the way you're most comfortable).
2. In the Task Manager Processes tab you'll want to locate every process that says either "Easy Settings", or "Samsung Easy", or possibly some other variations. Also you'll want to do this for each of the following "S Agent", "Samsung Agent", "Samsung Update", or similarly named samsung processes. You'll use each one of these in the next steps...
3. Right click each one of these 1 at a time and select "Open File Location" from the menu that appears. A folder will soon open with the executable file for this process highlighted somehow. Follow step 4 for this file and each additional one if any you find through the Task Manager.
4. If the file in fact lies somewhere within a "Samsung" related folder*** and seems to be related to Easy Settings** Samsung Update**, or Samsung Agent**,  you will then rename the file by simply placing an X in front of the name (easyblablabla.exe to Xeasyblablabla.exe). You will probably have to provide administrator credentials to do this and at the same time take note of the file location in the case that you want to reverse anything in the future by simply removing the X from the file name. *

*** Make sure each executable is within a Samsung related folder and that it seems to be directly related to Easy Settings, Samsung Update, or Agent.

** Don't just go renaming every process/file that relates to Samsung - as long as it is related to samsung and has "easy" or "agent" in its name somewhere you should be good to go - but still use a little judgement - I can't possibly know everything.

* Don't overdo it, just rename the 1 file that goes with the process you're working on and pay no attention to the rest of the files in that folder for now/ever.

5. After doing this for every process related to Samsung Easy Settings, you will have one last task and that is the "dreaded" registry edit (I'll make it fun and easy in step 6+)
6. On your Windows 10 bar click the Circle\Cortiana thing (next to or near the Window icon) and type REGEDIT in the search box - then open regedit and then you'll have to grant administrator privileges to do so completely.
7. In the Registry Editor select Edit->Find from the menu and type in "Easy Settings" (without quotes), and make sure the Values and Data checkboxes are selected (Select Keys too - why not) - and click the Find button. Likely it will find the entry in a folder with a mostly unreadable name (a bunch of letters and numbers). You'll go through the registry finding each entry with Easy Settings that meets step 8's requirements. (It will likely only be one entry, but maybe 2)
8. Very important... If you find a registry entry for Easy Settings that lies within one of the following 2 paths only ignoring all others (unless you know better) you will first Click (to make sure it is the right folder) and then if the data still has easy settings in it - right click the same highlighted (or encircled/squared) folder and select delete. Below are the only (as far as I know) following paths where it is safe to delete Easy Settings registry entries from so if you're in this path you should be 99.99% good to go (you can always back up your registry first, which is a good practice I will not teach here - do a search for it on Stackoverflow, Google, Bing, or somewhere else).

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

10. Now go check/refresh your Windows Settings "Apps & Features" to see if Easy Settings has been removed from the list. If it has, you've done good! Now try restarting your Windows Update to see if we did real good (you might have to restart your computer first) - you also might still get an error, in that case reload and retry to perform the update (could take a few tries - and you might have to restart your computer each time). But it will eventually work (especially if you don't get the annoying "Easy Settings" must be uninstalled first message again - and if you do - try steps 1 through 10 again following them more closely this time)

(Yes I skipped step 9 because if Microsoft can do it - so can I! =)

This is a rather "crude" but effective way around the issue, but it works, and if it works and allows you to install remaining Windows 10 updates without any further headache - it's worth it!!! Now you might lose some of the "Easy" button functionality on your Samsung device in doing this, but It had to be done to update Windows so this is expected. Check Samsung for any updates for their Easy Settings (I think they just call it Samsung Settings or something now), and any other relevant official Samsung updates/software for your device.

Goodnight and Goodluck!